# How to display or show notepad file using python

Tags: python-2.7, notepad

I have a notepad file in my PC with path D:/example.txt,how can i display this file using my python code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If you mean open the file with notepad:

Using [`os.startfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile) (only available in Windows):

```
import os
os.startfile(r'd:\example.txt')
```

Using [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) or [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
import subprocess
subprocess(['notepad', r'd:\example.txt'])
```

### To print to console

```
import sys

with open(r'D:\example.txt') as f:
    sys.stdout.writelines(f)
```

---

```
with open(r'D:\example.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.rstrip('\n')
```